# ASP.NET Webforms Parameter tampering

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, burp

I have been struggling at this for weeks. I have built a ASP.NET Web forms application and it is being audited for vulnerabilities.

Burp tool is being used for testing and it is able to intercept and edit the textbox values.

I have a simple form with textbox, button and I enter value "1234" in my txtUserID

[image]

Burp is able to intercept the POST request and edit the txtUserID value [squared in black below]
[image]

After editing the txtUserID textbox, the tampered value is reflected on the application.

[image]

Site runs on a self signed certificate . MAC has been enabled, Viewstate encrypted application level in the web config [in case its relevant for this]

Please help me on how do I fix this vulnerability?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you demonstrate is an example of [Main in the middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). The attacker is represented by Burp in your example.

The traffic from the browser to the server is safe, assuming the communication is encrypted (goes over SSL).

However, if the attacker acts as a proxy between the browser and the server, they can alter all the traffic.

The only noticeable difference for the client is the certificate - the attacker will never be able to pretend they use the original server's certificate, rather, the client will see the **attacker's certificate** in their browser.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, indeed its a MITM problem. Pardon my ignorance, but can you help me with links / procedures on how to mitigate it by validating the certificate?

Comment: @Chendur The certificate is displayed in the web browser, beside the url. If the browser believes the cert is invalid (which is the case when there's someone in the middle), the browser shows that there's a problem with the certificate. However, **there's no way** to do anything about it, no code to prevent it. It's just the user and their awareness.

Comment: What users can possibly do is to install a web browser extension that maintains a whitelist of known sites. There are a couple of such extensions in chrome extension store.

Comment: This has been highlighted as a vulnerability and I have to figure out a way to fix it for the application to move Prod. Is there a way I can hide this field "__viewstate" where my textbox values are displayed?

Comment: The fact that user can edit their own request with Burp on their machine was highlighted as vulnerability? There must be something else we're missing here.

Comment: Burp proxy server is being used for testing the MITM scenarios. Its acts as a web proxy between client and server.

https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/proxy/using

Comment: Then there's no way no mitigate such issues and someone who designs MiTM tests should be aware of this.